# Embedded form using default Symfony Type doesn't render an HTML field in data-prototype

Tags: symfony, collections

I have this Symfony Form that work well when I tried to generate a Collection form and render properly in HTML.

The **TestType** uses entry_type=>**PhoneType** which can be found here as well.

## TestType

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Core\SystemParameter;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class TestType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('value',CollectionType::class,array(

                'label'=>"Phone number list",
                'required'=>false,
                'entry_type'=>TextType::class,
                'entry_options'=>[
                    'label'=>'Phone Number'
                ],
                'allow_add'=>true,
                'allow_delete'=>true,
            ));

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'=>SystemParameter::class
        ]);

    }

}
```

## PhoneType

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PhoneType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('phone',TextType::class,array(
                'label'=>'Phone'
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
    }

}
```

However, instead of using a PhoneType that basically only contains a TextType, I would like to use a TextType in my TestType like shown below. Howver, it doesn't work, I don't have any error but the data-prototype doesn't contain the field to render the html input. What I'm I doing wrong ? It seems to me that what I want to do is similar to what is shown in the Symfony documentation:

## Data-prototype when using directly the Symfony TextType

No input field...

```
        <tr>
                                    <td>
                <a class="btn-sm remove c-yellow" title="Remove" href="#">
                    <strong>X</strong>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

## Data-prototype when using the PhoneType (working)

```
        <tr>
                                        <td class="field0">
                                        <input type="text" id="test_value___name___phone" name="test[value][__name__][phone]" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                                        <td>
                <a class="btn-sm remove c-yellow" title="Remove" href="#">
                    <strong>X</strong>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

## Expected Code without using the PhoneType

```
use App\Entity\Core\SystemParameter;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class TestType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('value',CollectionType::class,array(

                'label'=>"Phone number list",
                'required'=>false,
                'entry_type'=>TextType::class,
                'entry_options'=>[
                    'label'=>'Phone Number'
                ],
                'allow_add'=>true,
                'allow_delete'=>true,
            ));

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'=>SystemParameter::class
        ]);

    }

}
```

[Symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZzhw.png)

I expect it to work as shown in the Symfony documentation without having to create a new Type.

Comment: Hey there, I don't mean to be overly pedantic, but your question contains two code blocks for the TestType, **both** of which have entry_type TextType. In fact, both are identical. Additionally: the prototype itself gets rendered as well (in the view), and that is relevant code. But if everything looks *exactly* like you post here, I'd be out of ideas ;o/

Comment: What if you not link the Form to your class 'data_class'=>SystemParameter::class? Could you please show the code of SystemParameter ?

Answer (score 0):

After couple of hours of trying to figure out my issue, I figured out the problem... I was using a Twig form_theme that wasn't properly rendering collection prototype specifically when using Symfony core types.